# emacs isearch lazy highlight for whole buffer

Tags: emacs, elisp

the default behavior of isearch was highlighting the world that matched in current windows.
how can i change that behavior, let it highlighting the world that matched in the whole current buffer.

Comment: You don't see those matches anyway. What do you really want to achieve?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for the highlight-* commands, to keep things highlighted throughout the buffer whilst you perform other actions?

<kbd>M-s</kbd><kbd>h</kbd><kbd>C-h</kbd> lists:

```
Global Bindings Starting With M-s h:

key             binding
---             -------
M-s h l         highlight-lines-matching-regexp
M-s h p         highlight-phrase
M-s h r         highlight-regexp
M-s h u         unhighlight-regexp
```

You can also use <kbd>M-s</kbd><kbd>h</kbd><kbd>r</kbd> during an isearch to invoke highlighting for the current search term.

Tangentially, you can likewise invoke occur on the current search term with <kbd>M-s</kbd><kbd>o</kbd>

Use <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>b</kbd> during isearch to see all of the isearch bindings.

Comment: thanks, i know that way. but i still want todo that with isearch

Comment: i am trying to do that right now. how to invoke highlight-* automatic after isearch action. i am raeding isearch.el, but it's seem complex. can you give me some hits.

Comment: As long as you are running Emacs 23.1 or later, you should simply be able to type `M-s h r` during isearch. That should prompt you for the face to highlight with, just as if you'd typed `M-s h r` outside of isearch, but without the need to enter a regexp. So a complete sequence of keys might be: `C-s p a t t e r n M-s h r RET` to initiate a search for "pattern", and then highlight all instances of "pattern" in the default highlight face (hi-yellow).

Comment: You're welcome. I notice that you haven't accepted any answers for any of your questions, but you do seem to be happy with several of them. Please read the FAQ on how to ask questions and accept answers: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Comment: I'm sorry about that. i will check that.